# Websocket not working when deployed on server

Tags: asp.net-core, websocket

I am using websocket. When I run code through visual studio I am able to connect websocket hub using localhost. But when I deployed websocket hub on docker and trying to connect it is giving me error "The server's response was missing the required header 'Connection'." Below is code I am trying to use to connect to server

```
    private static void WebSocketClient(string webAddress)
    {
        var factory = new Func<ClientWebSocket>(() =>
        {
            var client = new ClientWebSocket
            {
                Options =
                {
                    KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)
                }
            };

            //  client.Options.SetRequestHeader("Upgrade", "websocket");
            return client;
        });

        var url = new Uri(webAddress);

        try
        {
            using (IWebsocketClient client = new WebsocketClient(url, factory))
            {
                var clientId = Guid.Parse("863924EF-083D-4DE4-B5B7-1BE3D7DA5CEA");
                client.ReconnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(200);
                client.ErrorReconnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
                client.ReconnectionHappened.Subscribe(type =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Reconnection happened, type: {type}, url: {client.Url}");
                    SendMessage(client, clientId, "S");
                });
                client.DisconnectionHappened.Subscribe(info =>
                    Console.WriteLine($"Disconnection happened, type: {info.Type}"));

                client.MessageReceived.Subscribe(msg =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Message received: {msg}");
                });

                Console.WriteLine("Starting...");
                client.Start().Wait();
                Console.WriteLine("Started.");

                Task.Run(() => StartSendingPing(client, clientId));
                //Task.Run(() => SwitchUrl(client));

                ExitEvent.WaitOne();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("====================================");
            Console.WriteLine("              Stop              ");
            Console.WriteLine("====================================");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{ex.Message}: {ex.InnerException?.Message}");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where you're deploying?

Comment: [Does `WDS_SOCKET_PORT=0` works for you?](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11779#issuecomment-1002506680)